# UML-Designer: No Folder UML Designer

Tags: eclipse, wizard, uml-designer

I am facing big troubles to use UML Designer.
It is installed in Eclipse but I can not make it work.

What am I doing wrong?

[UML Designer installed in Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cINyU.png)

[No UML Designer in Wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fDvj.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your first screenshot is pointing on the UML Java generators which are not parts of UML Designer 7.1.
What are you trying to do ? Use the UML to Java generators or the graphical modeler UML Designer?

Which version of Eclipse are you using and which version of UML Designer?
To create a new UML Designer project you should go in File > New Project > UML Designer > UML  Project.

Do you have errors in your errors log ?

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
I want to use the graphical modeler UML Designer. When I go to ile > New Project, I cannot find UML Designer > UML Project

I do not have error concerning UML Designer